# Combinations and arrangement

Tags: combinatorics

Twelve people are to travel by 3 cars, each of which holds four. Find the number of ways in which the party may be divided if two people refuse to travel in the same car.

My attempt,

I know the number of selection without restriction is equal to 34650. But I don't know how to proceed with number of selection when both in same car.

Comment: WLOG, there are car A, B and C. Let the pair be in Car A. Find the number of possibilities then times 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know the count when there is no restriction, (I have not verified it is 34650, but the procedure is the same) you can proceed as follows:

Now calculate the number of ways two specific persons $A, B$ can be put in the same car, and subtract that number from $34650$.

For definiteness put $A$  and $B$ in Car 1, calculate the count and then multiply that by 3 (the number of cars. I am assuming the cars are distinguishable.)

Comment: I don't understand how to calculate the number of ways for the two specific persons . Can you explain it for me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now how many ways 8 persons can be put into 2 cars (Car2, and Car 3) with 4  persons in each  car (no restriction!). Multiply this number by $10\choose 2$, the number of choices of person to accompnay $A,B$ in car 1.

Comment: Can I know why $10\choose 2$ ?

Comment: After $A$ and $B$ are put in car 1, from the remaining 10 we have to choose 2 persons to go  with them.